# Create a table with few conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables in SQL Server as below:

`EnquiryTable`:

```
EndID FyYear SNo ServiceID MaterialID 
55    2015   1   1         1
55    2015   2   5         3
```

`ServiceTable`:

```
ServiceID  ServiceName
1          ServiceA
2          ServiceB
3          ServiceC
4          ServiceD
5          ServiceE
```

`Material` table:

```
MaterialID   MaterialName
1            MaterialA
2            MaterialB
3            MaterialC
```

I need to return a table as below from a `stored procedure`, so that this table will help to bind a `gridview` ultimately.

Result table:

```
SNo  ServiceName   MaterialName
1    ServiceA      MaterialA
2    ServiceE      MaterialC
```

Basically need a procedure which will compare the `ServiceIds, MaterialIds` from `EnquiryTable` with `ServiceTable` and `MaterialTable`, and return back a resultant table with `ServiceNames` and `MaterialNames`.

I tried something like as below:

```
declare @serviceID int
declare @matID int
select sno, serviceid=@serviceID,materialid=@matID from dbo.enquirytable
```

but `@serviceID, @matID` variables are returned as `null`.

Experts please help.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Regards

Comment: You may find this helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a procedure using [CREATE PROC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) SQL keyword, then use the [EXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to execute the stored procedure.
Your select query and logic should be part of stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROC proc_NAME
@enqID int, @fyYear int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT E.SNO , S.ServiceName, M.MaterialName
    FROM EnquiryTable E
    INNER JOIN Service S ON E.ServiceID = S.ServiceID
    INNER JOIN Material M ON E.MaterialID = M.MaterialID
    WHERE E.EnqID=@enqID AND M.FyYear=@fyYear
END
```

you can execute this stored proc as

```
exec proc_NAME @enqID,@fyYear
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I can only pass enqID and fyYear to the procedure as params. You can see in the enquiryTable that enqID=55 and fyYear=2015. With these 2 params I get 2 rows in EnquiryTable, I gotta replace the service ids, material ids in these 2 rows with the service and material names from the service and material tables. Did you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Piyush, I got it. i very well know how to create a stored proc, but just wrote the question like it, coz I was trying few stuffs. Anyways thanks fr the answer, I will accept it.